# Algorithm: shortest path that passes through m different nodes

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

Suppose I have a weighted graph with n vertices and the starting point is given. The shortest path is defined as the path with the least sum of weights.

How can I find out the shortest path that passes through m different vertices ? (each vertex can be visited once or more than once. That is, there are exactly m vertices in the set of the vertices that have been visited, but each vertex may have been visited multiple times.)

Note that the number m is given but the specific m vertices are not. (These m vertices are selected by algorithm）

Is it an NP-Hard problem?

Comment: This feels like it should be on [mathematics.se]

Comment: How is "shortest" defined?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it feels like it should be on [mathematics.se]

Comment: @MoB.  Each edge has a weight, and the shortest path is defined as the path with the least sum of weights. There are exactly m nodes in the set of the nodes that have been visited, but each node may have been visited multiple times.

Comment: Ok, that's essential information that was missing. Please edit the question accordingly.

Comment: This is a generalisation of the travelling salesman problem (where m=n), so that means it's np-hard.

Comment: Sounds like it can be solved with some form of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can reduce the [Hamiltonian Path Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem) (HPP) to your problem: a Hamiltonian Path is a path in a directed unweighted graph that visits each vertex exactly once. To solve an instance of HPP, convert the graph into a weighted graph with weight 1 on every edge, set `m` to be `|V|` and solve your problem. This is a [polynomial-time reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_reduction), so your problem is NP-hard, since HPP is NP-complete.

It is also NP-complete since it is clearly in NP. So there is also a polynomial-time reduction from your problem to any other NP-complete problem. Algorithms for solving the Travelling Salesman Problem are probably most suited for you: see here for [details and examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Computing_a_solution).